# Why the last text block is not coming in the block content?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, algorithm, dictionary

I have a text file separated by new line or `-` character.

```
x = {"file_data":"               Bakery\r\n            Company GbR\r\n        Oranienburger Straße 120\r\n            10119 Berlin\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nBill no.3-7721         11:29:51 20.04.2021\r\n\r\n------------------------------------------\r\n1x Cappuccino          2,70€    2,70€  A\r\n\r\n                                  --------\r\n\r\nTotal          2,70€\r\n\r\nGiven (iZettle)                     2,7€\r\n\r\n\r\n------------------------------------------\r\nUSt.%     gross      net              USt.\r\nA=7%      2,70€     2,52€            0,18€\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n             Table: Counter\r\n          Terminal: Terminal 1\r\nTSE-Transaktion     1831\r\nTSE-Signatur-Nr.    98009\r\nTSE-Start           2020-04-21T09:29:38.00000Z\r\nTSE-Stop            2020-04-21T09:29:50.00000Z\r\nTSE-Seriennummer    5f2897cc074ae841330658eadd324661159f53b7ffd29215\r\nTSE-Zeitformat      utcTime\r\nTSE-Signatur        bXkPffFOcetbFokYrOqr/7EYrAc0PH6r\r\nTSE-Hashalgorithmus ecdsa-plain-SHA256\r\nTSE Status          In evaluation\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n         Ust-Id: DE11111111\r\n"}
```

My task is to get the position of every block and their content(blocks are separated either by:more than one new line character or a full line containing a separator `-`).

I wrote the below code and am able to get all the blocks except from the last block.

Here's my code, what I am missing here?

```
y = x["file_data"]

z = y.split('\r\n')

block = []
block_content = []

start_row, start_col, end_row, end_col = None, None, None, None
skip_line_count = 0

for i, row in enumerate(z):
    if any(letter.isalnum() for letter in row):
        if not start_row and not start_col:
            start_row = i
            start_col = row.index(row.replace(" ", "")[0])
            end_row = start_row
            end_col = row.index(row.replace(" ", "")[-1])
        else:
            end_row = i
            end_col = row.index(row.replace(" ", "")[-1])
    elif all(letter in ["", "-"] for letter in row):
        skip_line_count += 1
        if skip_line_count == 2 and start_row != None and start_col != None:
            block.append({
                "start_row": start_row,
                "start_col": start_col,
                "end_row": end_row,
                "end_col": end_col,
            })
            block_content.append(z[start_row : end_row + 1])
            start_row, start_col, end_row, end_col = None, None, None, None
            skip_line_count = 0
```

The expected `block_content` results should contain `TSE Status          In evaluation` as part of one the block.

Right now, the last `block_content` is

```
['USt.%     gross      net              USt.', 'A=7%      2,70€     2,52€         0,18€']`
```

Comment: It looks like, when you complete the for loop, if you have identified the startb of a block you should set end_row to the end of z and append the data to block_content

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Can you explain why `skip_line_count=4` when i = 38, it should be `2`. I am a bit confused here. logically, `skip_line_count` should not go above `2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @itprorh66 comment, I figured out the last missing logic. I had to add the block and block content append after the end of the loop.

```
block.append({
   "start_row": start_row,
   "start_col": start_col,
   "end_row": end_row,
   "end_col": end_col,
})
block_content.append(z[start_row : end_row + 1])
```